# If we created multiple resource of update request in REST,what will the impact at server side

Tags: rest

1. If we create the multiple resource of update request using POST method in REST.what will be the impact at server side if number of resource created .
2. I Know using put request ,we can achieve fault tolerance due to idempotence.if we use post instead put,what will happen?
3. If we created number of resource using post for update , is there any performance issue ?if we created number of resource then what is impact on server ?
4. In post and put if we call same request n times ,we are going to hit the server n time  then creating new resource and same resource should not impact on server.can please confirm this statement right or wrong .

Answer (score 0):

> If we create the multiple resource of update request using POST method in REST.what will be the impact at server side if number of resource created .

First of all, HTTP, the de-facto transport layer of REST, is an [application protocol for transferring documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s) and not just YOUR application domain you can run your business rules on. Any business rules you infer from sending data over the network are just a side-effect of the actual documentation management you perform via HTTP. While certain thins might map well from the documentation management to your business layer, certain things might not. I.e. HTTP isn't designed to support larger kinds of batch processing.

By that, even though HTTP itself defines a set of [methods](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3) you can use, with [IANA administering additional ones](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml), the actual implementation depends on the server itself. It should follow the semantics outline in the RFC, though it might not. It may harm interoperability with other clients though in such a case, that is why it is recommended to follow the spec.

What implications or impact a request may have on the server depends on a couple of factors such as the kind of the server, the data that needs to be processed and whether work can be offloaded, i.e. by a cache, as well as the internal infrastructure you use. If you have a server that supports a couple of hundred cores and terabytes of address space a request to be processed might have less of an impact on the server than if you have a server with only a single CPU core and just a gigabyte of RAM, which has to fit in a couple of other applications as well as the OS itself. In general though the actual impact a request has on the server isn't tide to the operation you invoke as at its core HTTP is just a remote document management protocol, as explained before. Certain methods, such as PATCH, may be an exception to this rule though as it clearly demands transaction support as either all or none of the operations defined in the patch document need to be applied.

> I Know using put request ,we can achieve fault tolerance due to idempotence.if we use post instead put,what will happen?

[RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) includes a hint on the difference between `POST` and `PUT`:

> The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT methods is highlighted by the different intent for the enclosed representation. The target resource in a POST request is intended to handle the enclosed representation according to the resource's own semantics, whereas the enclosed representation in a PUT request is defined as replacing the state of the target resource.  Hence, the intent of PUT is idempotent and visible to intermediaries, even though the exact effect is only known by the origin server.

`POST` does not give a client any promises on what happens in case of a network error i.e. You might not know whether a request reached the server and only the response got lost or if the actual request didn't make it to the server at all. [Jim Webber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=19m40s) gave an example why idempotency is important, especially when you deal with money and currencies.

HTTP is rather specific to inform a client when a resource was created by including a HTTP `Location` header in the response that contains a URI to the created resource. This works on `POST` as well as `PUT` and `PATCH`. This premise can now be utilized to "safely" upload data. A client can send `POST` requests to the server until it receives a response with a `Location` header pointing to the created resource which is then used in the next step to perform a `PUT` update on that resource with the actual content. This pattern is called the [`POST-PUT`](http://restalk-patterns.org/post-put.html) creation pattern and it is especially useful if you have either a large payload to send or have to guarantee that the state only triggers a business rule once, i.e. in case of an online purchase.

Note that with the help of [conditional requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) some form of optimistic locking could be used as well, though this would require to at least know the state of the current resource beforehand as here a certain value, that is unique to the current state, is included in the request that acts as distributed lock which, if different to the state the server currently has, as there might have been an update by an other client in the meantime, will result in a rejection of the request at the server side.

> If we created number of resource using post for update , is there any performance issue ?if we created number of resource then what is impact on server ?

I'm not fully sure what you mean by `created a number of resources using post for update`. Do you want to create or update a resource via `POST`? These methods just differ in the semantics they promise. How you map the event of the document modification to trigger certain business rules in your backend is completely up to you. In general though, as mentioned before, HTTP isn't ideal in terms of batch processing.

> In post and put if we call same request n times ,we are going to hit the server n time then creating new resource and same resource should not impact on server.can please confirm this statement right or wrong

If you send n requests via `POST` to the server, the server will perform the logic that should perform on a `POST` request n times (if all of the requests reached the server). Whether a new resource is created or not depends on the implementation. A `POST` request might only start a backing process, some kind of calculation or actually doing nothing. If one was created though the response should contain a `Location` header with the URI that points to the location of the new resource.

In terms of sending n requests via `PUT`, if the same URI is used for all of these requests, the server in general should apply the payload as the new state of the targeted resource. If it internally results in a DB update or not is an implementation detail that may very from project to project. In general a `PUT` request does not reflect in the creation of a new resource unless the resource the target URI pointed to didn't exist before, though it also may create further resources as a side-effect. Imagine if you design some kind of version control system. `PUT` is allowed to have side effects. Such a side effect may be that you perform an update on the HEAD trunk, which applies the new state to the HEAD, though as a side-effect a new resource is created for that commit in the commit history.

So in summary, you can't deduce the impact a request has on a server solely based on the HTTP operation you use as at its heart HTTP is just an application protocol that transfers documents over a network. The actual business rules that get triggered are just a side effect of the actual document management. What impact a request has on the server depends on multiple factors, such as the type of the server you use but also on the length of the request and what you do with it on the server. Each of the available methods has its own semantics and you shouldn't compare them by the impact they might have on the server, but on the premise they give to a client. Certain things like anything related to a balance or money should be done via `PUT` due to the idempotent property of that method.